# Get list based on containing string then order it by same number values in the list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have filled a list `lstLines` with some lines.

E.g list have some lines like under:

1. Column SName of Sheet [Sheet1] has missing cell value in row 6.
2. Column SName of Sheet [Sheet1] has missing cell value in row 9.
3. Column FName of Sheet [Sheet1] has missing cell value in row 6.
4. Column FName of Sheet [Sheet1] has missing cell value in row 11.
5. Column DOB of Sheet [Sheet1] has missing cell value in row 6.
6. Column FName of Sheet [Grade 4] has missing cell value in row 1.
7. Column DOB of Sheet [Grade 4] has missing cell value in row 3.
8. Column DOB of Sheet [Grade 4] has missing cell value in row 4.

Now Based on [Sheet1] and [Grade 4] create separate list. I have did this.

But I can't order the separated list based on the **row**(*these are at the end of each line*) values.

For example [Sheet 1] lines be in ascending according to row values (6, 9, 6, 11, 6, 6).

```
foreach (var item in _lstErrorSheets)
{
    var newlist = (from s in _lstLines where s.Contains(item) select s).ToList();
               foreach (var error in newlist)
               {
                    rtbDisplay.AppendText(lineNum +". "+error + " \r\n");
                    lineNum++;
               }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, this can be done using a single line:

```
var result = lstLines
    .Where(l => l.Contains("[Sheet1]"))
    .OrderBy(l => int.Parse(l.Substring(l.IndexOf("row") + 4).TrimEnd('.')));
```

Breakdown:
Use `Where` to filter the list, and `OrderBy` to sort it.
You want to sort by the numeric value of row, so you need to use `substring` to isolate the row number with the period at the end of each string, and then `trimEnd` to remove the dot, and finally `int.Parse` to get the number, otherwise `11` will come before `6` or `9`.